# Is there a way to bring together the objects drawn with Android OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: android, opengl-es

** I created a class to draw a line of one.↓↓

```
public class LINETEST{
float[] vertices = null;
private short[] indices = null;

public FloatBuffer verticesBuffer;
private ShortBuffer indexBuffer; 
private int LINE_NUMBER = 0;

public LINETEST() {

}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);
    gl.glLineWidth(2);
    gl.glColor4f(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, indices.length, 
              GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer); 

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

public void setBuffer() {

            ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            verticesBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
            verticesBuffer.put(vertices);
            verticesBuffer.position(0);

            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
            indexBuffer.put(indices);
            indexBuffer.position(0);            
}

public void setVertices(float[] verticesAl, short[] indicesAl, int number){

    this.vertices = verticesAl;
    this.indices = indicesAl;       
    this.LINE_NUMBER = number;

}

public int getLineNumber(){
    return this.LINE_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

** And drew value of the position of the array object declared by using this class is given in a different way.↓↓

`linetest = new LINETEST[2000];`

**And I will create a new object each time the line is drawn.↓↓↓

```
public void setVertices(float[] vertice, short[] indice, int lineNumber){
    this.vertices = vertice;
    this.indices = indice;
    this.number = lineNumber;

 linetest[number] = new LINETEST();
 linetest[number].setVertices(vertices, indices, lineNumber);       
 linetest[number].setBuffer();  

}
```

** Finally, I will draw an object that is generated by the OnDrawFrame of rendering class.↓↓↓

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
         if(vertices != null){
             if(linetest[number] != null){
                for(int i = 0; i<number; i++){
                    linetest[i].draw(gl);

                }
                 linetest[number].draw(gl);
             }

         }
}
```

** Can I be declared as one face of the line drawn in this way?

** Why I try to do this job is I wanted to put the color on the inside of the surface that are declared in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I misunderstand the question, but I believe you are trying to draw a face (or polygon) instead of lines. If your vertex and index buffers are set up appropriately then you may just need to change the type of primitive from GL_LINE_STRIP to something like GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. You will need to make sure your buffers are specified correctly for the primitive type you choose, and perhaps worry about face culling. From there you will need to apply a material or texture or both to fill in the polygons.

Comment: Sentence is awkward translation when I tried to to translate their translation Google Translate I do not have good English.

Comment: If you, if you'll excuse me I'll put my native language and write a sentence I want you to look at your translator to interpret. Native language is Korean.

Comment: 저는 OpenGL ES 에서 선을 하나 그리고 그 선들을 연결해서 하나의 도형처럼 인식하여 내부를 채우고 싶습니다.